# bitarray package for Python 2.7 on Windows?

Tags: python, bitarray

I need an easy to install version of bitarray for Python 2.7 on 32 bit Windows, for this project py2exe are not possible, so I need an exe / msi / egg that is simple for people to install, has anyone produced this? Google doesn't show up anything.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#bitarray

Bitarray is also part of [EPD](http://enthought.com/products/epd.php).

Answer (score 0):

[pyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is my weapon of choice. I feel it works much better than [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: This is to package a project for a client, but the main source needs to be able to be modified, so any "compilation" won't work I believe.